# d3.js force layout: force.linkDistance as function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I study d3.js library and I have a question about force layout and specifically about force.linkDistance.

For example, I have 3 points with coordinates A{x: 0, y:0}, B{x: 100, y: 100} and C {x: 300, y: 300}. According math the distance between points will be

AB = ((Xb-Xa)^2 + (Xb-Xa)^2)^(-2) = 141.4,

BC=  ((Xb-Xc)^2 + (Xb-Xc)^2)^(-2) = 282.8,

CA = ((Xb-Xa)^2 + (Xc-Xa)^2)^(-2) = 424.2.

So my question is , how to specify the distance between points like math does?
I would be very thankful if somebody will show me that actually in a live example in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Now if the points are fixed `A{x: 0, y:0}, B{x: 100, y: 100} and C {x: 300, y: 300}` then why force layout you can just draw lines between the points to connect it?

Comment: You may want to help people help you by creating the codepen or jsfiddle, and letting people fix it / finalize it....

Comment: Points are not fixed, i just wanted that distance between points was close to real